# MySQL transaction versus spam

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, transactions

I want a user to have a maximum of 3 entries in a table, I thought I'd need to use a transaction for this case to prevent any harmful spamming that might pass the 3 entry check. That's what I did and was left with the following code; a simplified version that removes all non-needed stuffs;

```
database.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
      if(err) return reject(err);

      connection.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM addresses WHERE uid = ${ database.pool.escape(uid) } AND status = 1 AND method = ${ database.pool.escape(method) } FOR UPDATE`, async function(err, result) {
        if(err){
          connection.rollback();
          return reject(err);
        } 
        if(result[0].total >= 3) return reject(`You have reached the max.`);

        try {
          var adress_obj = await get_address_here();
          connection.query(`INSERT INTO addresses SET label = ${ database.pool.escape(label) },
            method = ${ database.pool.escape(method) },
            wallet_address = ${ database.pool.escape(adress_obj.address) },
            address = ${ database.pool.escape(address) },
            uid = ${ database.pool.escape(uid) }`, function(err){

            if(err){
              connection.rollback();
              return reject(err);
            } 

            connection.commit(function(err){
              if(err){
                connection.rollback();
                return reject(err);
              }

              // Completed transaction, resolve promise
              resolve();
            });
          });
        } catch(err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
```

Alright, now what happens, is nothing really.. it doesn't differ from just calling two queries.. when a user spam clicks he is able to get through like 10 database entries when the maximum really should be 3.. what am I missing, do I even need to use a transaction for this? `FOR UPDATE` seemed to be needed for my purpose but I don't see it working either.

Also, the entries in the database are fine.. all that's wrong is that the transaction doesn't seem to work and is not preventing a spam action by users.

Comment: Did you start your transaction somewhere (`connection.beginTransaction`), or are you using `autocommit = 0`?

Comment: @Solarflare oof.. I never started the transaction :3